# VBA: Updating recordset in separate subroutine causes type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is a very strange bug I am experiencing here. Essentially what I am trying to do is create a new node with various properties when the recordset is empty and I want to put this functionality inside of its own function. But when I do that I get this error:

> Run time error '13': Type mismatch

If I do not put it in its own function everything works as expected. Here is my code with the extra subroutine that produces the error.

```
If Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!UseFTCheckBox Then

  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FTNodes WHERE ESDNodeID = " & Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!ESDNodeID & " ORDER BY ParentID,Sort"

  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

  'if the recordset is empty, there is no head node. create a new head node, then refresh the recordset
  If rst.EOF Then
     createHeadNode(rst) 'ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE
  End If
  ......
  ......
End If

Private Sub createHeadNode(rst As DAO.Recordset)
     rst.AddNew
     With rst
         .AddNew
         !FTNodeType = 1
         !Description = Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!Description
         !Sort = 1
         !ESDNodeID = Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!ESDNodeID
         .Update
     End With
End Sub
```

Structure of the FTNodes table that the recordset is using:

[image]

Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!Description is a textbox 
and
Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!ESDNodeID is also a textbox

Comment: You use `rst.AddNew` twice in `createHeadNode`

Comment: @VictorK That's true, but I doubt it is the source of the error (`.AddNew` adds a new record, and using it twice adds 2 records (1 blank one, 1 with values). @Luca please share the underlying table structure (types) and the content of the relevant variables (`Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!Description` and `Forms("Main")!ESDNodeDetails!ESDNodeID`). A type mismatch usually is just that, one of the table columns being set to a type it can't contain.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I just made an edit with the extra details. Could it be an error with converting the textbox string value to the ESDNodeID number field?

Comment: `createHeadNode` is a sub not a function. Execute without parenthesis`createHeadNode rst`.

Comment: @BitAccesser ahh that did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: createHeadNode(rst) is impossible; how on earth did you manage to have this code! Use the built-in Debugger :)  BitAccesser's suggestion is good; also createHeadNode (rst) is good (notice the SPACE!). DO debug please

Comment: @Gene: that's wrong, the parentheses are the problem (they evaluate `rst`, changing its type).

Comment: @Andre: I always use the "Call Subname" syntax, no parentheses. Anyway, try this--there is no point in arguing whatsoever:
    
    Sub a()  
       Call b(12, "abc") ' multiple arguments
       b 12, "abc" ' multiple arguments
       ' b (12, "abc") ' multiple arguments: the line will not compile at all
       c (12) ' single argument is passed!
       c 12 ' single argument is passed!
    End Sub

    Sub b(i As Long, s As String)
        Debug.Print 1; s
    End Sub

    Sub c(i As Long)
        Debug.Print i
    End Sub

Comment: Sorry, can't produce legible code her, for some reason...

Comment: Do this with a single recordset parameter, and you'll see. @Gene

Comment: @Andre: I do not understand your remark. Can you be more... descriptive? An example, perhaps? Did you try the code I provided?

Comment: @Gene: `Sub myRstSub(rst As DAO.Recordset)`, then call it with parentheses and without Call: `myRstSub (rst)` - you will get the Type Mismatch error as in the question.